# How to use a transformation to solve a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve:

$$\dot{y} = -\frac{2y(t)}{5t} +\frac{3}{5y(t)^4} $$

I was given a hint to use the transformation.

$$ z(t) = t^\alpha y(t)$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. I've seen this been done before but it seems like you just guess the solution. Is there a way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying throughout by $5y^4(t)$ and putting $y^5(t)=u(t)$ we have $5y^4(t)\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{du}{dt}$ thus our equation changes to $\frac{du}{dt}=-\frac{2u}{t}+3$putting $u=vt$ $\frac{du}{dt}=v+t\frac{dv}{dt}$ . Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write your equation in the form
$$5y'(t)y(t)^4+2\frac{y(t)^5}{t}=3$$
Now Substitute $$v(t)=y(t)^5$$ and multiply both sides by $$\mu=e^{\int\frac{2}{t}dt}=t^2$$
so you will get
$$t^2v'(t)+2tv(t)=3t^2$$
Now use that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(t^2v(t)\right)=3t^2$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Should it be $v = y^5$ there in the substitution?

Comment: Yes, it should be this.

Comment: Thank you. How did you get the idea to do $\mu$?

Comment: I have solved many of such equations

Answer (score 1):

Using the hint given we obtain
$$z'(t) = \alpha t^{\alpha - 1} y(t) + t^{\alpha} y'(t) = \frac{\alpha z(t)}{t} + t^{\alpha} y'(t)$$
which gives $\displaystyle y'(t) = \frac{z'(t) - \alpha z(t)/t}{t^\alpha}$.

Substitute this to the equation and simplify we got
\begin{align*}
\frac{z'(t) - \alpha z(t)/t}{t^\alpha} &= -\frac{2z(t)}{t^{\alpha + 1}}  + \frac{3t^{4\alpha}}{5 z^4(t)}\\
tz'(t) - \alpha z(t) &= - 2z(t) + \frac{3t^{5\alpha + 1}}{5z^4(t)}
\end{align*}
Taking $\alpha = 2$ we got $$tz'(t) = 3t^{11}/5z^4(t) \quad \iff z^4(t) z'(t) = 3t^{10}/5$$ 
Which can be solved easily by integrating.